# Error while apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, 20.04, ppa

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.

```
root@la425:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                       
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease                          
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu focal Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:3 https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:7 https://downloads.mariadb.com/MaxScale/2.4/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 https://downloads.mariadb.com/Tools/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:11 https://downloads.mariadb.com/MaxScale/2.4/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.20.67.208 443]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://downloads.mariadb.com/MaxScale/2.4/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: It seems you're using an invalid PPA (i.e. not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04). Try going to the 'software and updates' app and disabling all PPAs, then try again.

Comment: @OA The OS is barebone, no UI. How can I do this with commands?

Comment: Try this: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of the apt process, it seems you added manually some other unofficial repositories, which is okay. But when doing so you have to make sure they support you OS flavor, or at least the dists exist. You can't just add `focal` and hope it'll work.

When browsing manually to `https://downloads.mariadb.com/MaxScale/2.4/ubuntu`, there is no dist named `focal`, and this explains the `404  Not Found` error. Same goes for `http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu`.

The error `N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension` speaks a little bit by itself, and should be fixed.
You can read more about managing your sources and repo lists here: [Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)